# XAML in UWP : Customize tagname instead of Style attribute by using inheritance

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, controls

I'm beginning to work on XAML controls in a UWP App.

I want to create several variations of a same control (some kind of UI library), that will be reused in the app, let's say a "Big button" and a "Small button".

**Is there any performance problems, drawbacks, or better way to achieve the "custom tagname" control personalization ?**

(I personally found it way more readable and less error-prone once each control has been stylized.)

Thanks a lot!

---

**The "common" way** seems to create styles / templates based on Button, like so :

> Styles.xaml (ResourceDictionary)

```
<Style x:Key="MyBigButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="36"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="MySmallButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
</Style>
```

And then declare the controls as follow :

> MyView.xaml (Page)

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyBigButtonStyle}">My Big Button</Button>
<Button Style="{StaticResource MySmallButtonStyle}">My Small Button</Button>
```

---

**The "custom tagname" way**, for the sake of readability and simplicity (with custom as the correct namespace usage) :

> MyCustomButtons.cs

```
namespace MyApp.MyCustomComponents
{
    public sealed class MyBigButton : Button {}
    public sealed class MySmallButton : Button {}
}
```

> Styles.xaml

```
<Style Target="custom:MyBigButton">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="36"/>
</Style>
<Style Target="custom:MySmallButton">
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="10"/>
</Style>
```

> MyView.xaml

```
<custom:MyBigButton>My Big Button</custom:MyBigButton>
<custom:MySmallButton>My Small Button</custom:MySmallButton>
```

---

Comment: There are no performance drawbacks. All you're losing is simplicity. I guess there isn't any problem with readability.

Comment: It purely depends. If it is not just style but functionality of the control that you want to modify, the inherited control way is better. If it is just Style, you can create and use/reuse style keys.

Comment: See [Control Authoring Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether to create a custom control or re-template or re-styling an existing one depends entirely on your requirements. There are no "performance problems" involved in the decision.

If you don't intend to add any new *functionality* to a control, it doesn't make much sense to create another class like this:

```
public sealed class MyBigButton : Button {}
```

Then you might as well simply create a custom style or template.

Please refer to [Jerry Nixon's MSDN Magazine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt833441) article about how to create custom controls in XAML for more information.